# Having IEnumerable<T> declared inside interface while having IList<T> declared in concrete class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, ienumerable

Consider an example:

I have an interface like this. I need this interface to be covariant - meaning I have to declare my generic as "out" and use IEnumerable instead of list - and that's all. I'll use this just to simply get the elements that I need - nothing to insert.

```
    public interface IFoo<out T>
    {
          IEnumerable<T> Items { get; } 
    }
```

And then I have my concrete class declared like this:

```
    public class Foo : IFoo<Item>
    {
         // I have an error here : Type IList doesn't match the expected type IEnmerable
          IList<Item> Items { get; set; } 
    }
```

And I'm wondering why is that not possible? I mean IList inherits from IEnumerable and this type of code works completely fine.

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
{
    return new List() { new Item())};
}
```

Why it can be done? What are the workarounds?

My only solution is that I could just create additional property or method Like this

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetEnumerableItems()
{
   return Items;
}
```

But it seems too hacky for me. I thinking there could be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Interface methods cannot be implemented with covariant return types at all, irrespective of generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by the runtime. If you are implementing an interface which has a property that returns a particular type, you must match that return type exactly in your implementation.

[Return Type Covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns) was added in C# 9, but doesn't apply here (see @JeroenMostert's comment).

You can work around this by using explicit interface implementation:

```
public class Foo : IFoo<Item>
{
    IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Item> IFoo<Item>.Items => Items;
}
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxANwKYCcoDMCeAfAAQAYACAgRgBYBuAWACgGCBmMgJhIEkFUwSBvEgF8GTVrB7osEAMaouAMQD2SgDxKArghIAVAHwN+DEibLlmq/Vx5gAzgJIBzVAmrCGIxvRbsSypSQgiiqq3LwG9Eb0plwAMlC2CKE2eta89oLOriS2Lm6eMRQWYWCpnP7J4QB0JfYAvGU2tnT0QkA).

Consumers which have a `Foo` can access `Foo.Items` and get an `IList<Item>`. Consumers which just have an `IFoo<Item>` can instead access `IFoo<Item>.Items`, and will get back an `IEnumerable<Item>`.

Comment: Return type covariance also works for properties, but only for classes, and only if you override the property "proper" (not adding a setter). That is, `abstract class FooBase : IFoo<Item> { public abstract IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; } }` makes `class Foo : FooBase { public override IList<Item> Items { get; } }` legal.

Comment: Love it. That's what I was looking for. Thank you ;)